# I dont understand xaml alignment

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, alignment, uwp-xaml

So I struggle with the `XAML` alignment a bit and I hoped for someone who could help me get trough it.

This is the Code. I will break it down below:

```
<Grid x:Name="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Click="ShowPopupOffsetClicked"/>
        <Image Source="Assets/images/icon_thumbnail.png"></Image>
    </StackPanel>
    <Popup VerticalOffset="60" HorizontalOffset="0" x:Name="StandardPopup">
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
            Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            BorderThickness="2" Width="300" Height="350">
            <StackPanel >
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run x:Name="MyRun" Text=""/>
                </TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBox x:Name="searchTextBox" Width="200" Height="30"   />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Button x:Name="firstSearch"  Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped" >
                            <Image Source="Assets/images/view_search.png"/>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="previous" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/images/left_arrow.png"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="next" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"  Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/images/right_arrow.png"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Close" Click="ClosePopupClicked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

This part will be `MyRun` Text later:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run x:Name="MyRun" Text=""/>
</TextBlock>
```

This part is the `SearchBar` and the `search-button` which should be perfectly in line. How do I do this?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBox x:Name="searchTextBox" Width="200" Height="30"   />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button x:Name="firstSearch"  Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped" >
            <Image Source="Assets/images/view_search.png"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

This is the next and previous button. It should be perfectly in line with `MyRun`. How would I do that?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button x:Name="previous" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
        <Image Source="/Assets/images/left_arrow.png"/>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="next" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"  Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
        <Image Source="/Assets/images/right_arrow.png"/>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And at last will be the "Close" Button. I guess it is kinda already perfect?:

```
<Button Content="Close" Click="ClosePopupClicked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

Now a screenshot of how it Looks like and how I want it to look:

This is how it is:

[image: How it is]

This is how I want it to be:

[image: How I want it]

I know that I can Change the height of the popup. But when I Change the height some Things disappear (for example the close Botton won't be visible because it is too far down while the popup height is too low).

Sorry for the long post. I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: This seems like a job for a `Grid`... inside your border, id use a grid they are a bit easier for more complex layouts, however more verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a `Grid` with three `RowDefinitions`. Something like this:

```
<Popup VerticalOffset="60" HorizontalOffset="0" x:Name="StandardPopup">
    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                BorderThickness="2" Width="300" Height="350">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- row 1 -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox x:Name="searchTextBox" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="0,0,3,0" />
                <Button x:Name="firstSearch"  Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped" >
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/view_search.png"/>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>

            <!-- row 2 -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="previous" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/images/left_arrow.png"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="next" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}"  Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/images/right_arrow.png"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run x:Name="MyRun" Text=""/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>

            <!-- row 3 -->
            <Button Grid.Row="2" 
                    Content="Close" Click="ClosePopupClicked" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

You can adjust the space between the controls using the `Margin` property.